# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 not giving error without building

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

My visual studio 2015 lost its capabilities to detect errors on a class without building. Before I'm able to receive errors after pausing typing but now its not giving any.

Here in this image.
[image: No error]

You can clearly see that i typed an invalid keyword on VS but after waiting for so long or even saving the file multiple times, it's not giving any error. Any way to fix this?

Comment: According to this thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303388/vs-2015-community-not-checking-errors-until-build-errors-do-not-go-away
you just do a new project in VS and then reload the old one.I cannot test it as the error does not occur on my machine.

Comment: There also used to be an option to turn off the checking - but I think they removed it in 2015, so you cant even disable it, and re-enable

Comment: @bidy that didnt work

Comment: Any 3rd party components installed, like Resharper for example? Try deactivating those.

Comment: @bidy I tried launching VS with all extensions disabled, same result, i have no resharper

Comment: There is a limit to how much the IntelliSense parser can do.  If there are critical errors in the code before this then it has to give up to avoid generating thousands of subsequent errors that are not actually logical errors but just a side-effect of declarations that could not be parsed.  If it gets into that state then you just waited to long and it is really time to start fixing code.

Comment: @HansPassant there's a fact that will invalidate that, im working on a  collaborative environment and there's no problem in their VS.

Comment: If you cannot give a practical example that easily reproduces the problem on other programmers' machines then you'll have to use Microsoft Support to get help.