# The event 'foo' is not a RoutedEvent

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015, routed-events

I tried making a Routed Event in a user control of an existing project and I'm getting the error message `The event 'foo' is not a RoutedEvent.`

To make sure I wasn't crazy, I made an example project with *just* the offending code ([a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Only I don't get any error message in my example project.
But it's the exact same code!

## Does anyone have any ideas what's going on?

Even with the error message, the project compiles and the RoutedEvent works!

I tried cleaning the project, rebuilding, restarting VS and my PC, but no matter what I do this error message persists.

I beleive this is just an IDE issue.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

[image: IDE=VS2015Pro]

#### UserControl1.xaml.cs

```c#
namespace Okuma_FFP
{
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;

    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(fooEvent, this));
        }

        public static readonly RoutedEvent fooEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
            "foo", RoutingStrategy.Direct, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(UserControl1));

        // Provide CLR accessors for the event 
        public event RoutedEventHandler foo
        {
            add { AddHandler(fooEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(fooEvent, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

#### UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Okuma_FFP.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Okuma_FFP"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:UserControl1.foo">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation  
                        To="Blue"
                        Duration="0:0:5" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>
    <Grid>  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an IDE bug.
Possible duplicate: [Visual Studio displaying errors even if projects build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17703004/2596334)

I took a hint from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36297609/2596334) and made sure to exit VS in-between cleaning the solution and building.

> 1. Delete all obj, bin, release, and debug folders
> 2. Delete `Project_Folder\.vs\Project_Name\v14\.suo`
> 3. Open the solution in Visual Studio
> 4. Clean Solution
> 5. Exit Visual Studio
> 6. Open the solution again
> 7. Build, build, build...
> 8. Confirm it's fixed and go get coffee