# Library is missing in my code file while my project referenced the correct dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

why when i pull the project from the visualstudio team explorer, the assembly showed as red color line while my project is able to build.

[image]

The project is able to build with the error. How i make my project does not show the red color line anymore?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567945/type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist
Please follow this link. It may help you

Comment: what version of VS are you using? Are you sure the .cs file you are showing us is in the same project in the solution explorer? What version of the framework?

Comment: Not having any knowledge of that library, all I'll do here is emphasise - assembly names and namespace names matching is a *convention*, not a requirement. So, check that library and see what namespaces its types are actually in.

Comment: @Prabhanshutiwari that one is not fixing my problem, i checked it is same framework , and their problem is cannot compile, i am able to build but just showing red line

Comment: @noobed 4.6.1, visual studio 2017

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the namespace that i specificied in the picture i double checked, it does exist in the name space of that library.

Comment: Well, I trust Visual Studio more, so the only other possibility I can think of at the moment is that you're inspecting the wrong set of references in the solution explorer.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever but i can build everything, but the color is still show

Comment: Could you try to Clean the solution, close VS, open VS, Build again?

Comment: Looks like the community has already stumbled upon the same issue you are having in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703004/visual-studio-displaying-errors-even-if-projects-build

Comment: @noobed it solved my problem thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is, find the root path of the project, go find the path of the hidden directory .vs , delete everything inside .vs/{project-name}/ , it solve my problem