# ReSharper In An Unreal Engine Project Giving Wrong Errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper, unreal-engine4

I know about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703004/visual-studio-displaying-errors-even-if-projects-build). However, I tried every single answer and none of them worked.

I just created a new Unreal Engine Project, and enabled ReSharper. When I created a new Actor class, it's showing errors with red squiggly lines, even though I can run it just fine.[image: Visual Studio Screenshot] Why is this happening? I disabled code analysis squiggles, like the documentation said.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. You have to go to the Unreal Editor, and click File | Refresh Visual Studio Project. Then when you open Visual Studio it won't show the errors.

Comment: you should add the answer to your question on the ReSharper Forum